# Update isEmailVerified without logging out

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, swiftui

I am trying to update the isEmailVerified property without logging out of the application. So far I've been able to only update it when I log out of the application.

Here is what I have so far:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var session: SessionStore

    var body: some View {
        
        Group {
          
            if (self.session.session != nil) {
                
                let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
                
                VStack{
                    
                    Text("Logged In As \(user?.email ?? "")")

                    Text("\(String(self.session.session!.isEmailVerified!))")
                    
                    Button(action: {user?.sendEmailVerification { (error) in
                                        
                    }}){
                    Text("Verify email")
                    }
                    
                    Button(action: {session.signOut()}){
                        Text("Sign Out")
                    }
                }
            
          } else {
            
            OnBoardingView()
            
          }
            
        }.onAppear(perform: {
            
            session.listen()
            
        })
    }
}
```

and

```
struct User {
    
    var uid: String
    var email: String?
    var isEmailVerified: Bool?
    
    init(uid: String, displayName: String?, email: String?, isEmailVerified: Bool?) {
        self.uid = uid
        self.email = email
        self.isEmailVerified = isEmailVerified
    }

}



class SessionStore : ObservableObject {
    
    var didChange = PassthroughSubject<SessionStore, Never>()
    var isLoggedIn = false { didSet { self.didChange.send(self) }}
    @Published var session: User? { didSet { self.didChange.send(self) }}
    var handle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?
    
    init(session: User? = nil) {
        self.session = session
    }

    func listen () {
        // monitor authentication changes using firebase
        handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
            if let user = user {
                // if we have a user, create a new user model
                print("Got user: \(user)")
                self.isLoggedIn = true
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.session = User(
                        uid: user.uid,
                        displayName: user.displayName,
                        email: user.email,
                        isEmailVerified: user.isEmailVerified
                        
                    )
                }
                
            } else {
                // if we don't have a user, set our session to nil
                self.isLoggedIn = false
                self.session = nil
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    
    @discardableResult func signOut () -> Bool {
        do {
            try Auth.auth().signOut()
//            self.isLoggedIn = false
//            self.session = nil
            return true
        } catch {
            return false
        }
    }


    func signUp (
        email: String,
        password: String,
        handler: @escaping AuthDataResultCallback
        )
        {Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: handler)}

    func signIn (
        email: String,
        password: String,
        handler: @escaping AuthDataResultCallback
        )
        {Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: handler)}


    
}
```

So far the two solutions I've gotten are that I need to refresh the user object using the following:

```
Auth.auth()?.currentUser.reload()
```

Or I can force it to get a new ID token using:

```
func getIDTokenResult(forcingRefresh forceRefresh: Bool, completion: ((FIRAuthTokenResult?, Error?) -> Void)? = nil)
```

However, since I'm new to coding I'm not sure I would implement this in my code. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Since you've already found two promising methods, how about trying to get them to work first? Then if you get stuck doing that, show what you tried in your question and it's more likely we can help.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I understand what you're saying. I'm new to coding so I'm not even sure where to start. I've searched for more detailed explanations based on those two solutions but I haven't found anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is quite an old discussion thread, but it seems no one has answered your question. If I am understanding your issue correctly, you can refresh the .isEmailVerified value (in Swift 4) like so:

```swift
Auth.auth().currentUser?.reload(completion: { (error) in
     if let error = error {
          // There was an error reloading the currentUser object
          // Do something with the error here
     } else {
         // Success! 
         // Do anything you wanted to do with the refreshed .isEmailVerified in here!
         print("The refreshed .isEmailVerified = \(Auth.auth().currentUser?.isEmailVerified)")
    }
})
```